# i am struggling to install brave browser via sudo apt install

Tags: apt, dependencies

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
curl : Depends: libcurl4 (= 7.81.0-1) but 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but your message is correct for example for *jammy* or 22.04; ie. I'd expect `libcurl4 | 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.10 | jammy-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which would imply your system is *behind on upgrades*, or what you're trying to install is *for another system* or again *outdated*, so return to basics on your *unstated* OS, start with `sudo apt update`, apply all upgrades & then read all messages (*not just the bit you pasted here!*)